# Custom Block “Invalid Block Type”, even-though everything looks correct

Tags: layout, blocks, extensions, template, layout-update

I'm trying to write a module with a custom block that inject some javascript to the page head. no matter what I do I keep getting "invalid block type" error.

Note: I went over **all** the questions here about "invalid block type" and none of them worked / were relevant.

my extension files look like this:

[image]

**my config file (Packname/Core/etc/config.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packname_Core>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Packname_Core>
  </modules>

  <global>  
    <blocks>
      <packname_core>
        <class>Packname_Core_Block</class>
      </packname_core>
    </blocks>
  </global>

  <frontend>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <packname>
          <file>packname_core.xml</file>
        </packname>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

**my layout file (design\frontend\base\default\layout\packname_core.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
                <block type="packname_core/injectjs" name="packnameJs" as="packnameJs" template="packname/injectjs.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**and my block file (Packname\Core\Block\Injectjs.php):**

```
<?php

class Packname_Core_Block_Injectjs extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getPacknameJsUrl()
    {
        return Mage::helper('packname_core/config')->getJsUrl();
    }
}
```

**now the error I'm getting looks like this:**

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Packname_Core_Block_Injectjs' in C:\Bitnami\magento-1.9.2.1-1\apps\magento\htdocs\app\Mage.php:595
```

the name Packname_Core_Block_Injectjs seems correct, I already double checked uppercase/lowercase issues, and I can't figure out what's wrong.. everything seem in place.

note that if I set block type to something like "core/html" I no longer get the error, but then offcourse I can't access my block functions.

any help will be greatly appreciated! 
thanks,

Comment: <codePool>community</codePool> did you check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried this code and could not find the error check your configuration

app/etc/modules/Packname_Core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packname_Core>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Packname_Core>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/community/Packname/Core/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packname_Core>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Packname_Core>
  </modules>

  <global>  
    <blocks>
      <packname_core>
        <class>Packname_Core_Block</class>
      </packname_core>
    </blocks>
  </global>

  <frontend>

            <routers>
                <packname_core>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Packname_Core</module>
                        <frontName>packname</frontName>
                    </args>
                </packname_core>
            </routers>

    <layout>
      <updates>
        <packname>
          <file>packname_core.xml</file>
        </packname>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/packname_core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <packname_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
                <block type="packname_core/injectjs" name="packnameJs" as="packnameJs" template="packname/injectjs.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </packname_index_index>
    </default>
</layout>
```

app/code/community/Packname/Core/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class Packname_Core_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function IndexAction()
    { 

        $this->loadLayout()
                   ;                 
    $this->renderLayout();

    }
}
```

app/code/community/Packname/Core/Block/Injectjs.php

```
class Packname_Core_Block_Injectjs extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getPacknameJsUrl()
    {
        return Mage::helper('packname_core/config')->getJsUrl();
    }
}
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/packname/injectjs.phtml

```
<div>adaskd;asdask;lad gfdfgfd </div>
```

Comment: wow you took a lot of effort to help me out, thanks! I compared my code to your example and it looks the same except for the "<packname_index_index>" tag in the layout file, since I need this layout to update all pages, not just the router I define. error still occur. is the <packname_index_index> mandatory? I want it to affect all pages. thanks

Comment: No this is for your page for test but no errors disabled the cache and remove var/cache then check

Comment: did it, error still happens. is there a chance you can upload your extension zip somewhere and post the link? PS I have magento 1.9.2.1, if that matters. thanks.

Comment: Try to replace all files with my files and then and head will no add phtml file you want add open page.xml of any theme and check how they are adding it

Comment: did that, I don't see error but I don't see the "daskd;asdask;lad gfdfgf" div either (obviously in /packname url). are you sure your code works? do you see the div? thanks, (PS: I added "<?php" to begining of all files, I assume you just left them out since it doesn't work without it)

Comment: remove this before="-" from packname_core.xml it all set to go

Comment: still nothing :( are you using the same magento as me? 1.9.2.1? I literally copied all your files and I don't see the div in my page. :( I can tell you two things: 1. the controller is called, I added log there and saw it in the log. 2. when I remove "<packname_index_index>" the error comes back (the original error), on all pages. did it really work for you? can you please upload the code?

Comment: did you able to see this text? adaskd;asdask;lad gfdfgfd

Comment: nope.. sorry its taking so long, I appreciate your effort very much. but are you using the same version? ( 1.9.2.1)

Comment: i added the file path too maybe helpful

Comment: its the same. can you please confirm that we are even on the same version ( 1.9.2.1) and/or upload the files?

Comment: i don't have files right now i am on mobile now. yes we are same version.

Comment: oh snap apparently I had a syntax error in some unrelated Helper and that somehow caused it.. I guess related to cache/compilation process or whatever. anyway fixed that, cleared the entire cache, enabled compilation again then disabled it, somehow things now work. thank you very much for the help. I feel like I can't choose your answer as the right answer because to be fair you couldn't find the problem without that extra file, but I did give +1. thanks again :))

Comment: lol i was expecting that but you always talk about invalid block error. it is always difficult to find problem in custom module

Comment: indeed I might have been misleading with the question. I let my guessing and assumptions get in the way :)